# Problem using WinDDK 7 with VC6

Tags: visual-c++-6

When I try to build a VC6 project with WinDDK 7600.16385.0, I get the following error

C:\SDK\Microsoft\WinDDK\7600.16385.0\inc\api\winefs.h(387) : error C2485: 'deprecated' : unrecognized extended attribute

Because I'm not directly including Winefs.h in my project, I'm not able to conditionally build the project for removing 'deprecated' error.

I would like to know if WinDDK 7600.16385.0 can be used with VC6.

Any potential help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: WinDDk7 is fairly new, I suspect it would be difficult at best.